# Replace 2 characters inside a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string and I want to fill all the blank values with 0 between to `,`  :

`var initialString = 3,816,AAA3,aa,cc,bb,5.9,27,46,0.62,29,12,7,10,13.1,86,6.02,20,1.68,8,0.24,48,22,6.2,0.9,,,1,`

I want this output :

`var finalString = 3,816,AAA3,aa,cc,bb,5.9,27,46,0.62,29,12,7,10,13.1,86,6.02,20,1.68,8,0.24,48,22,6.2,0.9,0,0,1,0`

I try to use replace

`var newString = initialString.replace(/,,/g, ",0,").replace(/,$/, ",0");`

But the finalString looks like this:
 `var initialString = 3,816,AAA3,aa,cc,bb,5.9,27,46,0.62,29,12,7,10,13.1,86,6.02,20,1.68,8,0.24,48,22,6.2,0.9,0,,1,0`
Some coma are not replaced.

Can someone show me how to do it?

Comment: Replace `/,(?=,|$)/g` with `,0`.

Comment: Your idea is correct, but the mistake you made is the regex consumes 2 commas at once. So it won't replace the last comma if there are odd number of commas. Using a lookahead solves this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can match a comma which is followed by either a comma or end of line (using a forward lookahead) and replace it with a comma and a `0`:

```js
const initialString = '3,816,AAA3,aa,cc,86,6.02,20,1.68,8,0.24,48,22,6.2,0.9,,,1,';

let result = initialString.replace(/,(?=,|$)/g, ',0');

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You saved me lot of time and frustration.

Answer (score 0):

using [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```js
var str = "3,816,AAA3,aa,cc,bb,5.9,27,46,0.62,29,12,7,10,13.1,86,6.02,20,1.68,8,0.24,48,22,6.2,0.9,,,1,";
const result = str
  .split(",")
  .map((s) => (s === "" ? "0" : s))
  .join(",");
console.log(result);
```